# "Possible Duplicate" objection

Tags: discussion

I would like to discuss this "Possible Duplicate" closure.

My question: [How to force load desktop version of website?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10959/how-to-force-load-desktop-version-of-website)

The "original" question: [How can I change the user agent for the stock browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6233/how-can-i-change-the-user-agent-for-the-stock-browser)

My objections are:

- How to change the user agent and how to load the desktop version of a site are two different questions.
- Changing the user agent is valid but maybe not the only answer to my question.
- Because I didn't know that changing user agent can force load the desktop version I wasn't able to find the answer. More and more people will have the same problem and there will be more and more duplicates like mine.

What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: Part of the reason we keep around the "closed as duplicate" questions is precisely because people have different ways to search for the same information. The closed questions act as a "gateway" for alternative search terms.

Comment: As for re-opening, the standard mechanism is for 5 people with sufficient reputation points to vote to re-open. As a Mod I can do it myself, but there _were_ three other people who also voted to close before I acted. If I re-open it may end up being closed again anyway. I'd like to hear from a few more users about this before acting unilaterally.

Comment: The search "gateway" makes sense. There is still the question whether the "original" question (changing user agent) is the only answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Other than "Find somewhere on the webpage with a 'main site' link and click it," there's really no other answer to your question.  There are site-specific methods, such as appending `&m2w` to a Facebook URI, but those would be impossible to all list in an answer.

Sites that care about the user agent may load a movile version; sites that don't care show the same site to everyone.  It's really the only reliable way to determine if someone is using a mobile or not.

I did consider this issue before voting to close, but in addition to above I agree with Al's reasoning: People searching for either version will find the answers, since your question is now linked to mine.  If a question came up about using Firefox or another browser to do this, that would not be a dupe since it's excluded from my question.

Comment: I agree with you, especially after the search "gateway" explanation. Unfortunately there is a negative emotion associated to the act of closing your question, as if I didn't my homework and didn't check the other questions first, as if did something wrong. Event the sticker says "...covers exactly the same ground...". Maybe it would be worth rethinking the message.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek That's probably a fair point. I should remember to leave an explanatory comment for my vote, as well.